# Converting object into time and grouping/summarizing time (H/M/S) into 24 hours

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I subsetted a big dataframe, slicing only one column `Start Time` with `type(object).

```
test = taxi_2020['Start Time']
```

Got a column

```
0          00:15:00
1          00:15:00
2          00:15:00
3          00:15:00
4          00:15:00
         ...   
4137289    00:00:00
4137290    00:00:00
4137291    00:00:00
4137292    00:00:00
4137293    00:00:00
Name: Start Time, Length: 4137294, dtype: object
```

Then I grouped and summarized it by the count (to my best knowledge)

```
test.value_counts().sort_index().reset_index()
```

and got two columns

```
     index  Start Time
0   00:00:00    24005
1   00:15:00    22815
2   00:30:00    20438
3   00:45:00    19012
4   01:00:00    18082
... ... ...
91  22:45:00    32365
92  23:00:00    31815
93  23:15:00    29582
94  23:30:00    26903
95  23:45:00    24599
```

Not sure why this `index` column appeared, now I failed to rename it or convert.

What do I would like to see?

My ideal output - to group time by hour (24h format is ok), it looks like data counts every 15 min, so basically put each next 4 columns together. `00:15:00` is ok to be as `0` hour, `23:00:00` as `23rd` hour.

My ideal output:

```
Hour Rides
0    34000
1    60000
2    30000
3    40000
```

I would like to create afterwards a simple histogram to show the occurrence by the hour.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: `index` columns appear because you did `.reset_index()`. instead do `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: Also, to get your desired hourly output, do is your `test.str[:2].astype(int).value_counts().sort_index()`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, thanks, where do I put it `test.str[:2].astype(int).value_counts().sort_index()`? In the end?

Comment: Right after definition of `test`.

Comment: If I do `drop = True`, my time is dropped, I have only counts, this does not work for me. Your second suggestion also does not work, I get `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
#Create dummy input datafframe
test = pd.DataFrame({'time':pd.date_range('2020-06-01', '2020-06-01 23:59:00', freq='15T').strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
              'rides':np.random.randint(15000,28000,96)})
```

Let's create a DateTimeIndex from string and resample, aggregate with sum and convert DateTimeIndex to hours:

```
test2 = (test.set_index(pd.to_datetime(test['time'], format='%H:%M:%S'))
             .rename_axis('hour').resample('H').sum())
test2.index = test2.index.hour
test2.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    hour  rides
0      0  74241
1      1  87329
2      2  76933
3      3  86208
4      4  88002
5      5  82618
6      6  82188
7      7  81203
8      8  78591
9      9  95592
10    10  99778
11    11  85294
12    12  93931
13    13  80490
14    14  84181
15    15  71786
16    16  90962
17    17  96568
18    18  85646
19    19  88324
20    20  83595
21    21  89284
22    22  72061
23    23  74057
```

Comment: thanks! You answered it faster, while I was summarizing my solution and answered my question myself. Appreciate your time and efforts, will accept your answer as a solution for the community! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step by step I found answer myself

Using this code, I renamed columns

`test.rename(columns = {'index': "Time", 'Start Time': 'Rides'})`

Got

[image]

The remaining question - how to summarize by the hour.

After applying

```
test2['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(test2['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
test2
```

I came closer

[image]

Finally, I grouped by hour value

```
test3 = test2.groupby('hour', as_index=False).agg({"Rides": "sum"})
print(test3)
```

[image]